# Umbraco on Azure and Forms

Tags: azure, umbraco

I used the Azure portal to install an instance of Umbraco.

I need to use the Umbraco forms for a simple contact form.

The Umbraco instance contains the forms and I can perfectly create and configure everything I need about forms (fields, workflows, ...).

Problem is that I can't get to have it on any page.

The video [here](https://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/extending/umbraco-forms/adding-forms-to-your-templates/) shows how to do it but when I click on the button as shown 23 seconds in the video, I can't find the forms and therefore not add my forms.

I tried to add the Razor line that it seem to generate based on the guid I get on the Form configuration page but when I save, the online page (I mean, the page of the actual website) is crashing (Yellow asp.net error page).

Does anybody knows what is going on here?

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that I did click on the Install button in the Forms section and waited until it refreshed the page. Surprisingly, it continues to prompt for installation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Seems like when we installed Umbraco at first on Azure, the auto install failed at taking the database into account.

We had to manually edit the config file to make sure everything was all right.

However, some bits for the Forms were not referenced properly.

So I uninstalled the forms completely and reinstalled them from scratch and it started to work fine.